# Android/Ionic Bug: Gray Screen before SplashScreen - How to remove?

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, splash-screen

When application starts (on Android Device) a gray screen and then a white screen appears before SplashScreen. How can i remove that?

No Solution i found in the internet helps me..

Comment: can u post code?? what exactly in happening in you launcher activity. This could be due to some memory consuming task being performed on main thread.

Comment: Thats my MainActivity.java.  Is that what you mean by posting code or do you need another?

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initializes the Bridge
    this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
      // Additional plugins you've installed go here
      // Ex: add(TotallyAwesomePlugin.class);
      add(GoogleAuth.class);
      add(FacebookLogin.class);
      add(StoragePlugin.class);

    }});
  }
}